# Python Regex Pattern Advice

Tags: regex

I am having a problem with Regex in my python script, I have never really understood it to be honest and still find it confusing but I think in this instance I need it. Here is my problem.

Below is the output I have saved as a string:

```
cd /dev;ls | grep st
[root@modi ~]# cd /dev;ls | grep st
nst0
nst0a
nst0l
nst0m
st0
st0a
st0l
st0m
stderr
stdin
stdout 
vhost-net
[root@modi dev]#
```

From this string I am trying to identify and save "st0" to a variable to be used later on, however there may be more results than just st0 that need to be found. The number is automatically generated when a new device is connected to the server (therefore there could be st0, st1, st2 infinitely and I want to save all of the results in a tuple)

Can anyone tell me what regex pattern I should use to identify "st" as the first two characters and obtain the subsequent numbers afterwards?

Thanks

Comment: So, what have you tried? What do you mean by "the first two characters"? Where?

Comment: By the first two characters I mean "st" and by where I mean in the output string I have copy and pasted. I have tried re.findall(r'\bst\b',output) which returns ['st', 'st'] but I dont know how to get the two characters afterwards

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'\bst\d+\b',output)`. If you mean the `st\d+` as a whole line cotntent, use `re.findall(r'(?m)^st\d+$',output)`

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these return a result, I was hoping from the string I pasted the output would be [st0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use either of the two solutions below:

```
re.findall(r'\bst\d+\b',output)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VQfpT3/1). Here, `\bst\d+\b` matches `st` + one or more digits in between word boundaries (in between the start/end of a string or non-word chars).

Or, if you mean the `st\d+` should be a whole line, use

```
re.findall(r'(?m)^st\d+$',output)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bgHD2r/1). Here, `st\d+` is only matched as a whole line due to `^` and `$` anchors (that match line boundaries due to the `(?m)`, inline `re.MULTILINE` modifier option).

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/0DS227):

```
import re

reg = r"\bst\d+\b"
s = "Last login: Thu Mar 16 23:04:57 2017 from 16.29.4.112\ncd /dev;ls | grep st\n[root@modi ~]# cd /dev;ls | grep st\nnst0\nnst0a\nnst0l\nnst0m\nst0\nst1\nst0a\nst0l\nst0m\nstderr\nstdin\nstdout \nvhost-net\n[root@modi dev]#"
res = re.findall(reg, s)
print(res)
# => ['st0', 'st1']
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither instance worked I even tried re.findall(r'\bst0\b',output) In an attempt to find the the word inside the string exactly and even that doesn't return anything

Comment: Then your input is different from the one you posted. Or you did not even try my code.

Comment: The String Im Searching:                                                                                                                                                                  
cd /dev;ls | grep st
[root@modi ~]# cd /dev;ls | grep st
nst0
nst0a
nst0l
nst0m
st0
st0a
st0l
st0m
stderr
stdin
stdout
vhost-net
[root@modi dev]#

Comment: Is it  a string? Or a list? What errors do you get?

Comment: Its A string, I dont get any errors but I save the regex to a variable e.g.         split = re.findall(r'\bst\d+\b',output)                                                             and print the output which gives me                                                                             []

Comment: Then you should provide exact steps, as you see, I cannot repro.

Comment: What more steps do you require? I have a big string which I have provided in which I want to find a word ("st") and any subsequent numbers after it using regex. Im not aware of any more steps I have taken that benefit the situation. The output string is a recived output from a paramiko command if that helps?

Comment: Anything that clarifies the situation, because both of my regexp solutions find expected matches in the *string* you provided.

Comment: Ok so I just instead of saving the paramiko output to a variable manually created a variable and copy and pasted the information into it, I had to make it all on one line to be recognised as a string but afterwards it would appear your regex provided works perfectly. It seems to be an issue with the format of the output being on separate lines that is messing up the regex

Comment: Or the input is not a string. Try to pass `"\n".join(paramiko_output)` to `re.findall`. Or vice versa: `paramiko_output[0]`

Comment: It seems to be a string, I have been able to do re.split commands in the past successfully also I have tried converting the output to a string ( myoutput = str(paramiko_output)) and have had the exact same outcome as before.          print paramiko_output[0] returns the first character as you would expect from a string